# Java Bind connected to the Caché code has been deprecated, how to replace?

Tags: java, intersystems-cache

Currently, I have used the following code (JDBC way) to connect to InterSystem Caché:

```
import java.sql.*;

import com.intersys.jdbc.CacheDataSource;

/**
 * @author prd
*/
public class NewTinyBind {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Connection dbconnection = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    try {
        String url = "jdbc:Cache://localhost:1972/SIMPLE";
        String username = "_SYSTEM";
        String password = "SYS";
        CacheDataSource cds = new CacheDataSource();
        cds.setURL(url);
        dbconnection = cds.getConnection(username, password);
        stmt = dbconnection.createStatement();
        java.sql.ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(" SELECT * FROM TEST ");
        int cols = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
        while (rs.next()) {
            for (int i = 1; i < cols + 1; i++) {
                String colname = rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i);
                Object value = rs.getObject(i);
                System.out.println("colname:" + colname + ",value:" + value);
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            stmt.close();
            dbconnection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

}
```

I would like to use this way (Java Bind) to connect to InterSystem Caché, but I am in my environment (jdk 1.8), the following code is prompted out of date (@ java.lang.Deprecated), but the document does not prompt how to replace these outdated The code that someone knows? Thank you.

code by https://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=BLJV_using#BLJV_using_objects_sample

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import com.intersys.objects.*;

public class SampleApplication {
  public static void main(String[] args){
      Database dbconnection = null;
      String url="jdbc:Cache://localhost:1972/SAMPLES";
      String username="_SYSTEM";
      String password="sys";
      ObjectServerInfo info = null;
      Sample.Person person = null;

      try {
          // Connect to Cache on the local machine, in the SAMPLES namespace
          dbconnection = CacheDatabase.getDatabase (url, username, password);

          // Open an instance of Sample.Person,
          // whose ID is read in from the console
          InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
          System.out.print("Enter ID of Person object to be opened:");
          String strID = br.readLine();

          // Use the entered strID as an Id and use that Id to
          // to open a Person object with the _open() method inherited
          // from the Persistent class. Since the _open() method returns
         // an instance of Persistent, narrow it to a Person by casting.
          person = (Sample.Person)Sample.Person._open(dbconnection, new Id(strID));

          // Fetch some properties of this object
          System.out.println("Name: " + person.getName());
          System.out.println("City: " + person.getHome().getCity());

          // Modify some properties
          person.getHome().setCity("Ulan Bator");

          // Save the object to the database
          person._save();

          // Report the new residence of this person */
          System.out.println( "New City: " + person.getHome().getCity());

          /* de-assign the person object */
          dbconnection.closeObject(person.getOref());
          person = null;

          // Close the connection
          dbconnection.close();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
      System.out.println("Caught exception: "
        + ex.getClass().getName()
        + ": " + ex.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

[image: Caché jdk 1.8 API - Java Bind]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [same question](https://community.intersystems.com/post/java-packages-deprecated) on InterSystems Developer Community portal.
Documentation [says](http://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=BLJV_preface):

> **Important**:
>
> **The Caché Java Binding is Deprecated**
>   Java Persistence Architecture
>   (JPA) is the recommended persistence technology for complex object
>   hierarchies in Java projects. Caché and Ensemble currently support JPA
>   1.0 and 2.0 via the Hibernate implementations of the JPA specifications. See “Using the Caché Hibernate Dialect” in Using Caché
>   with JDBC.
>
> Extreme Event Persistence (XEP) is the recommended
>   persistence technology for high-performance simple to medium
>   complexity object hierarchies in Java projects. See “[Using eXTreme
>   Event Persistence](https://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=BXJV_xep)” in Using Java with Caché eXTreme.